# Obtain browser url in php for rewritten URL

Tags: php, web-services, mod-rewrite, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I have written a restful api that uses the following apache mod rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/api/index.php?request=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, in the controller, I found that I've been unable to properly obtain the query string.

When I tried to obtain the query string after making a get request to https://example.com/api/search/article?mh=7 :(1)

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

I got the following result:

```
request=search/article
```

When I tried the following:(2)

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

I got the following result:

```
/api/index.php?request=search/article
```

What can I do to appropriate use mod rewrite and also successfully obtain the query string in my api controller?

Note: Actual url's have been changed for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your htaccess is in `/api/` folder, it should look like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Note: don't use `http://` in your rule otherwise it will be an external redirect. Also, use `QSA` flag to append query string from initial url.

From your example: `https://example.com/api/search/article?mh=7` will be rewritten to `/api/index.php?request=search/article&mh=7`

---

EDIT: if you want each `http` url of your API to redirect to `https` equivalent

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /api/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/api/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes, I need the url to redirect to https, however, in the event that http is included...How would I incorporate that requirement into your answer?

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect each `http` url to `https` equivalent ? The code in my answer is working for both, no matter if it's `http` or `https`

Comment: Yes. Just out of curiosity, though, would that be bad practice for an api? Just to give you an idea, this isn't going to be a publicly accessible api.

Comment: I edited my answer with a rule to redirect `http` to `https`. Well i think it's not a good or bad practice, this is more a personal choice